# profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = false not working for me

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

Using watir-webdriver for automation I'm not able to handle Firefox "Untrusted Connection" . Already tried this:

```
 require 'watir-webdriver'
 profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
 profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = false
 browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox, :profile => profile)
 browser.goto("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.com)
```

Still got the same result ? Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to handle Firefox Untrusted Connection"? What is the error or unexpected behaviour that you are seeing?

Comment: When FF opens with the url "http://__.___.___.com" FF opens displaying page "This connection is untrusted" (It appears due to issues with site's SSL certificate). All i want is that whenever i run my script this page should not get displayed & the url should open directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
   @profile=Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name "default"
   @profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer=false
   @profile.secure_ssl = true 
   browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => @profile
```

Comment: Yoy can also create your own custom profile, accept all certificates for the site and then use above code.

Answer (score 0):

Capabilities help me:

```
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(accept_insecure_certs: true)
$driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, desired_capabilities: capabilities
```

geckodriver 0.14.0, Mozilla Firefox 52.0, selenium-webdriver 3.2.1

Comment: Reference to an official document: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings#ssl-certificates